# back button not working on sencha touch

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, push

I'm pushing a view from my navigation view (xtype : 'mainPanel') like this. It's an element of  tabbar. In the 2nd view  a `back` button is displayed in navigation bar,But it's not working. Any idea?

```
itemtap: function(list, index, target, record) {


                                list.up('mainPanel').push({
                                    xtype: 'newview',
                                    title: 'New',
                                    data: record.data
                                });


}
```

Main.js

```
Ext.define('Proj.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar','Proj.view.phone.Mainpanel','Proj.view.phone.Home',''
],
config: {
    tabBar: {
        docked: 'bottom',
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        }

    },

    items: [

        {
            xtype: 'homePanel'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'mainpanel'
        },

    ]
}
```

});

Mainpanel.js

```
Ext.define('Proj.view.phone.MainPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'mainpanel',
    requires : [
        '],
    initialize:function(){

        this.getNavigationBar().add(stuff);


Ext.getCmp('categoryList').setData(jsonObject.info);



    },
    config: {
        title : 'Shop',
        iconCls: 'favorites',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        scrollable: true,

            items: [

                        {
                            xtype: 'list',
                            fullscreen: true,
                            itemTpl: '{name}',
                            autoLoad: true,
                            id:'categoryList',
                            store: {
                                fields :['active', 'created','description']

                            },
                            listeners: {
                                itemtap: function(list, index, target, record) {

                                    list.up('mainpanel').push({
                                        xtype: 'newview',
                                        title: 'newview',
                                        data: record.data
                                    });

                                }
                            }
                        }
            ]
    },
```

Comment: Any errors in the console ? Could post a bit more code (navigationview, tabbar...)

Comment: No error in console.will post code

Comment: @TDeBailleul Please check my update in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try overriding the back button event with the following code ::

```
extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype:'myNavigation',
config:{
    ……
},
onBackButtonTap:function(){
    this.callParent(arguments); 
    alert('back button pressed');
}
```

See if that works. If it does, then you'll know you're handling the back event wrong, and the push isn't working. If it doesn't throw up the alert, then the listener isn't working. Try to programmatically call the back event using a controller method, and see if that works instead

Comment: In Sencha 2.2.1 you get an error for `this.callParent(arguments);`
but you can use `this.pop()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem before. Create an initialize function in all views. Add this code in it.

```
this.callParent(arguments);
```

Comment: how will that help ? what does it do ?